# openmp Linker flags in MSVC

Tags: visual-c++, linker, openmp

when I try to compile my project in MSVC2008 with the linker flag (Configuration properties>>Linker>>Command line>> Additional options) set to :
"/STACK:10000000 /machine:x64 /openmp" 
it warns me that the /openmp flag is unknown.
"LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/openmp'; ignored"
I want to know that MSVC automatically links the openmp libs when I added the compiler flag (Configuration properties>>C/C++>>Command line>>Additional options) 
" /Zm1000 /EHs /MP /openmp /fp:fast" 
or I should do sth else for getting rid of the warning.

Answer (score 1):

The `/openmp` switch should be applied to the compiler, not linker. You can switch it on in `C/C++ -> Language -> Open MP Support`. The compiler then automatically instructs the linker to include the corresponding libraries.